# equality of limits related to harmonic numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Let $H_{n,k}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j^k}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}H_{n,k}=H_{\infty,k}$ for $k >1$. I need to prove that

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k H_{n,k} }{k} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k H_{\infty,k} }{k}.
\end{equation}

I tried to prove that for all $\epsilon >0$, there is $N$ natural number such that for all $n>N$:
\begin{equation}
\left|\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (H_{\infty,k}-H_{n,k}) }{k}\right|<\epsilon,
\end{equation}

for this, I tried to use the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} (H_{\infty,k}-H_{n,k})=0$, but with this I could not complete the test.